# Not able to set Initial value in ngx-bootstrap typeahead

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-5, ngx-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Hello I am using angular 16
"ngx-bootstrap": "^11.0.2",

I can not set default value means when user select the data from suggestive search and i have saved that value in DB and now when you load this control i want to pre fill selected value
Below is the code in HTML

I am using  [typeaheadAsync]="true"

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="search" 
typeaheadOptionField="AgencySearchText" 
[typeahead]="suggestions$"
[typeaheadAsync]="true" 
[typeaheadMinLength]="4" 
[optionsListTemplate]="customListTemplate"
class="form-control" 
[name]="label" 
(keydown)="onTypeaheadKeyPress($event)"
(typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)" 
[required]="required" 
[disabled]="disabled">
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.suggestions$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<string | undefined>) => {
      observer.next(this.search);
    }).pipe(
      switchMap((query: string) => {
        if (query && query.length > 3) {
          return this.srvAgency.GetSearchAgencyLookup(query)
        }
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  }
```

I have tried the official site but they do not have such example

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/typeahead?tab=overview.

Answer (score 0):

The `ngmodel` for the control is bound to a variable named `search`. You should be able to just do `this.search = "apple"`